# CSS header with Table cell

Tags: css

I have a little issue related to a header where a small height come up and i do not know how to remove it.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper_header">

<div class="left_header">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="central_header fondo_amarillo">
    <div class="aleron_izquierdo"></div>
    <div class="menu_option"><a href="#">Option 1</a></div>
    <div class="menu_option"><a href="#">Option 2</a></div>
    <div class="menu_option"><a href="#">Option 3</a></div>
    <div class="menu_option"><a href="#">Option 4</a></div>
    <div class="menu_option"><a href="#">Option 5</a></div>
</div>
<div class="right_header fondo_amarillo">&nbsp;</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper_header {
    width:100%;
    display:table;
}
.central_header {
    width:500px;
    display:table-cell;
}
.left_header {
    display:table-cell;
}
.right_header { display:table-cell; }
.left_header { 
    background-image:url(http://www.alarconrotulos.es/img/amarillo_cabecera_izq.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
.aleron_izquierdo {
    width:130px;
    height:69px;
    background-image:url(http://www.alarconrotulos.es/img/pestana_cabecera_peque_960.png);
    position:relative;
    left:-130px;
    float:left;
}
.menu_option a {
    font-size:18px;
    height:69px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    color:rgb(150,150,150);
    float:right;
    padding:0 5px;
    display: block;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-align: end;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    display: -moz-box;
    -moz-box-align: end;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    display: box;
    box-align: end;
    box-pack: center;
}
.menu_option a:hover {
    color:rgb(84,84,84);
}
.fondo_amarillo {
    background-color:#FFFF58;
}
```

Here you run the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/aL447/

When you run the code, you will see that the central_header block has three pixels higher than it should be and I can not understand why.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, cells (or elements displayed as cells in CSS) are aligned vertically to baseline.
You expect **`vertical-align: top`** in this case, here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aL447/3/)

baseline makes sense when you're aligning an input and a label or text and an image and each are of different height. But for layout, it's more likely to be top or bottom values, maybe middle. Be sure to test with an item occupying 2 lines by forcing it with a 
 (worst case)

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset it with this [reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) code

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

.wrapper_header {
    width:100%;
    display:table;
}
.central_header {
    width:500px;
    display:table-cell;
}
.left_header {
    display:table-cell;
}
.right_header { display:table-cell; }
.left_header { 
    background-image:url(http://www.alarconrotulos.es/img/amarillo_cabecera_izq.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
.aleron_izquierdo {
    width:130px;
    height:69px;
    background-image:url(http://www.alarconrotulos.es/img/pestana_cabecera_peque_960.png);
    position:relative;
    left:-130px;
    float:left;
}
.menu_option a {
    font-size:18px;
    height:69px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    color:rgb(150,150,150);
    float:right;
    padding:0 5px;
    display: block;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-align: end;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    display: -moz-box;
    -moz-box-align: end;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    display: box;
    box-align: end;
    box-pack: center;
}
.menu_option a:hover {
    color:rgb(84,84,84);
}
.fondo_amarillo {
    background-color:#FFFF58;
}
```

I have placed everything here you need to change with your CSS code.

Comment: It does, it resets your whole css. So it will bring it 5-10px up on top. Did you replace my whole css with yours? Try it out in JSFiddle aswell.

Comment: Yes i did, but the gap already is visible. I run your link and happens the same.

Comment: then it might be the browser you are running. running an old browser? everything works fine here with the reset code in chrome.

Comment: I use Chrome and Mac OSX. latest release